# Assign value of pointer to pointer in array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I would like to assign a character in a string to the first character of string in array of strings, equivalently I would like to assign a pointer in an array of pointers to the value of another pointer.

I have tried the following:

```
char ** array=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10);
char * str="like";

*(array[0])=*str;
*(array[0])=str[0];
**(array)=*str;
**(array)=str[0];
```

These seem like they are assigning the value of value of the first pointer.

I keep getting a segmentation fault error.

Comment: `array of strings` is the array of arrays. You allocate memory only for first array (that one that will hold another arrays, by the way - not correctly) and you should iterate over elements of `array` and allocate memory for another arrays. See google 2d arrays in C

Comment: You need the right mindset. Use box-and-pointer diagrams, e.g. http://www.rose-hulman.edu/Users/faculty/young/CS-Classes/archive/csse120-old/csse120-old-terms/201340/Resources/C/BoxAndPointerDiagrams/discussion.pdf  then it will all become clear.

Comment: What computer are you on which can have a pointer size of 1, 2, 5, or 10 (divisors of the 10 bytes you allocate)?

Comment: @Weather Vane: Ok yeah I just fixed that.

Comment: @dylan7, see here http://rextester.com/WSKM94472

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was misunderstanding what happens when an array of pointers is created. I assumed that C actually created the pointers in an array and didn't just allocate space for them.

The fix:

```
char ** array = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 10);
    char tok = *ts; /* create character that has value of a pointer */

    char *token =&tok; /* create new pointer that points to same value as *ts but in a different address */
    array[0]=token; /* assign the pointer */
```